# How can I change the content of the modal based on the input of the user

Tags: javascript, html, modal-dialog

So I've been trying to find a method to display the results of a questionnaire and I tried to use a modal as is looks better than just an alert button, which should display a different piece of information based on the inputs of the user in the questionnaire. I created a few functions which return the values that i want to display in the modal but I don't know how to incorporate them into the modal content. I don't know if that is possible and if not what other methods would you suggest to display the information to the user?

```js
function fn1() {

  var score = 2.5;
  var bmi1 = document.getElementById("bmi1");
  var bmi2 = document.getElementById("bmi2");
  var bmi3 = document.getElementById("bmi3");

  var contraNo = document.getElementById("contraNo");
  var contraOral = document.getElementById("contraOral");
  var contraIud = document.getElementById("contraIud");

  var hrtNo = document.getElementById("hrtNo");
  var hrtConti = document.getElementById("hrtConti");
  var hrtNon = document.getElementById("hrtNon");

  var diabYes = document.getElementById("diabYes");
  var diabNo = document.getElementById("diabNo");

  var pcosYes = document.getElementById("pcosYes");
  var pcosNo = document.getElementById("pcosNo");

  var nulliparity = document.getElementById("nulliparity");
  var parOver1 = document.getElementById("parOver1");


  if (bmi1.checked == true)
    score = score + 0;
  else if (bmi2.checked == true)
    score = score + 1.85;
  else if (bmi3.checked == true)
    score = score + 4.675;
  else if (bmi4.checked == true)
    score = score + 6.175;

  if (contraNo.checked == true)
    score = score + 0;
  else if (contraOral.checked == true)
    score = score - 0.8;
  else if (contraIud.checked == true)
    score = score - 1.2;

  if (hrtNo.checked == true)
    score = score + 0;
  else if (hrtConti.checked == true)
    score = score - 0.675;
  else if (hrtNon.checked == true)
    score = score + 0.5;

  if (diabYes.checked == true)
    score = score + 1.375;
  else if (diabNo.checked == true)
    score = score + 0;

  if (pcosYes.checked == true)
    score = score + 3.75;
  else if (pcosNo.checked == true)
    score = score + 0;

  if (nulliparity.checked == true)
    score = score + 1.075;
  else if (parOver1.checked == true)
    score = score - 0.8;

  var percentage = Math.round((score * 100) / 100);

  return score;

}

function category() {
  var result1 = fn1();
  let category;
  if (result1 >= 1 && result1 <= 3.5)
    category = "low";
  //alert("Your risk category is low ");

  else if (result1 > 3.5 && result1 <= 6.5)
    //  alert("Your risk category is medium ");
    category = "medium";

  else if (result1 > 6.5)
    category = "high";
  //  alert("Your risk category is medium ");

  return category;
}
/* function displayResult() {
  let category1 = category();
  var result = fn1();

  alert(result);
  alert(category1);
  return false;
}*/

document.getElementById("btn1").addEventListener("click",
  function() {
    document.querySelector(".bg-modal").style.display = 'flex';
  });

document.querySelector('.close').addEventListener('click',
  function() {
    document.querySelector(".bg-modal").style.display = 'none';
  });

//incorporate the functions fn1() and category() in the modal
```

```css
.bg-modal {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  position: absolute;
  top: 250px;
  right: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: none;
}

.modal-content {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: skyblue;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 14px;
  font-size: 38px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>

<body>

  <h1>Endometrial Cancer Predictor </h1>

  <h3>What is your BMI?</h3>

  <input id="bmi1" type="radio" name="grp1" value="0"> less than 25 </input> <br>

  <input id="bmi2" type="radio" name="grp1" value="1.85"> 25 to 29 </input> <br>

  <input id="bmi3" type="radio" name="grp1" value="4.675"> 30 to 39 </input> <br>

  <input id="bmi4" type="radio" name="grp1" value="6.175"> over 40 </input>


  <h3>Do you take contraception?</h3>

  <input id="contraNo" type="radio" name="grp2" value="0"> No <br>

  <input id="contraOral" type="radio" name="grp2" value="-0.8"> Oral Contraception <br>

  <input id="contraIud" type="radio" name="grp2" value="-1.2"> Intrauterine Device (IUD)


  <h3>Do you take HRT?</h3>

  <input id="hrtNo" type="radio" name="grp3" value="0"> No <br>

  <input id="hrtConti" type="radio" name="grp3" value="-0.675"> Continous <br>

  <input id="hrtNon" type="radio" name="grp3" value="0.5"> Non Continous



  <h3>Do you suffer from Type 2 Diabetes?</h3>

  <input id="diabYes" type="radio" name="grp4" value="1.375"> Yes <br>

  <input id="diabNo" type="radio" name="grp4" value="0"> No


  <h3>Do you suffer from PCOS?</h3>

  <input id="pcosYes" type="radio" name="grp5" value="3.75"> Yes <br>

  <input id="pcosNo" type="radio" name="grp5" value="0"> No


  <h3>What is your parity?</h3>

  <input id="nulliparity" type="radio" name="grp6" value="1.075"> 0 <br>

  <input id="parOver1" type="radio" name="grp6" value="-0.8"> +1

  <br>
  <br>

  <button id="btn1" onclick="displayResult()">Submit </button>

  <div class="bg-modal">
    <div class="modal-content">

      <div class="close">+</div>

      <script src="index.js"></script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: can you add a jsfiddle or codepen link?

Answer (score 0):

It's not pretty, but this shows you how to get the values from your functions and show them in the modal.

```js
function fn1()
{

    var score=2.5;
    var bmi1 = document.getElementById("bmi1");
    var bmi2 = document.getElementById("bmi2");
    var bmi3 = document.getElementById("bmi3");

    var contraNo = document.getElementById("contraNo");
    var contraOral = document.getElementById("contraOral");
    var contraIud = document.getElementById("contraIud");

    var hrtNo = document.getElementById("hrtNo");
    var hrtConti = document.getElementById("hrtConti");
    var hrtNon = document.getElementById("hrtNon");

    var diabYes = document.getElementById("diabYes");
    var diabNo = document.getElementById("diabNo");

    var pcosYes = document.getElementById("pcosYes");
    var pcosNo = document.getElementById("pcosNo");

    var nulliparity = document.getElementById("nulliparity");
    var parOver1 = document.getElementById("parOver1");


    if(bmi1.checked==true) 
        score=score+0;
    else if(bmi2.checked==true)
        score=score+1.85;
    else if(bmi3.checked==true)
        score=score+4.675;
    else if(bmi4.checked==true)
        score=score+6.175;

    if(contraNo.checked==true) 
        score=score+0;
    else if(contraOral.checked==true)
        score=score-0.8;
    else if(contraIud.checked==true)
        score=score-1.2;

    if(hrtNo.checked==true) 
        score=score+0;
    else if(hrtConti.checked==true)
        score=score-0.675;
    else if(hrtNon.checked==true)
        score=score+0.5;

    if(diabYes.checked==true) 
        score=score+1.375;
    else if(diabNo.checked==true)
        score=score+0;

    if(pcosYes.checked==true) 
        score=score+3.75;
    else if(pcosNo.checked==true)
        score=score+0;

    if(nulliparity.checked==true) 
        score=score+1.075;
    else if(parOver1.checked==true)
        score=score-0.8;

        var percentage = Math.round((score *100) /100);

           return score;

}

function category()
{
    var result1= fn1();
    let category;
    if (result1>=1 && result1<=3.5)
    category= "low";
        //alert("Your risk category is low ");

    else if (result1>3.5 && result1<=6.5)
      //  alert("Your risk category is medium ");
        category= "medium";

        else if (result1>6.5)
         category= "high";
      //  alert("Your risk category is medium ");

      return category;
}
      /* function displayResult() {
        let category1 = category();
        var result = fn1();

        alert(result);
        alert(category1);
        return false;
      }*/

document.getElementById("btn1").addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.querySelector(".bg-modal").style.display = 'flex';
    document.getElementById("modal").innerHTML = "fn1: " + fn1() + " Cat:" + category();
});

document.querySelector('.close').addEventListener('click', function(){
    document.getElementById("modal").innerHTML = "";
    document.querySelector(".bg-modal").style.display = 'none';
});

   //incorporate the functions fn1() and category() in the modal
```

```css
.bg-modal{
width: 500px;
height: 300px;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
position: absolute;
top: 250px;
right: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
display: none;

}

.modal-content{
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: skyblue;
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
    position: relative;
}

.close{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 14px;
    font-size: 38px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html>

<head> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>

<h1>Endometrial Cancer Predictor </h1>

<h3>What is your BMI?</h3>

<input id="bmi1" type="radio" name="grp1" value="0">
less than 25 </input> <br> 

<input id="bmi2" type="radio" name="grp1" value="1.85">
25 to 29 </input> <br>

<input id="bmi3" type="radio" name="grp1" value="4.675">
30 to 39 </input> <br>

<input id="bmi4" type="radio" name="grp1" value="6.175">
over 40 </input>


<h3>Do you take contraception?</h3>

<input id="contraNo" type="radio" name="grp2" value="0">
No <br>

<input id="contraOral" type="radio" name="grp2" value="-0.8">
Oral Contraception <br>

<input id="contraIud" type="radio" name="grp2" value="-1.2">
Intrauterine Device (IUD)


<h3>Do you take HRT?</h3>

<input id="hrtNo" type="radio" name="grp3" value="0">
No <br>

<input id="hrtConti" type="radio" name="grp3" value="-0.675">
Continous <br>

<input id="hrtNon" type="radio" name="grp3" value="0.5">
Non Continous



<h3>Do you suffer from Type 2 Diabetes?</h3>

<input id="diabYes" type="radio" name="grp4" value="1.375">
Yes <br>

<input id="diabNo" type="radio" name="grp4" value="0">
No


<h3>Do you suffer from PCOS?</h3>

<input id="pcosYes" type="radio" name="grp5" value="3.75">
Yes <br>

<input id="pcosNo" type="radio" name="grp5" value="0">
No


<h3>What is your parity?</h3>

<input id="nulliparity" type="radio" name="grp6" value="1.075">
0 <br>

<input id="parOver1" type="radio" name="grp6" value="-0.8">
+1

<br>
<br>

<button id="btn1" >Submit </button>

<div class="bg-modal">
<div id="modal" class="modal-content">
</div>
<div class="close">+</div>
</div>
<script src="index.js"></script>


</body> 

</html>
```